# Parsing an un-named JSON array in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json

**My question:** How can I break up and iterate through the JSON array pictured below?

I am making an AJAX web app and I need to serialize an array of objects in Javascript and put them in a url to pass to a php script. This is all going fine and the php script recieves the JSON like so..

```
$passed = $_GET['result']; 
if(isset($passed)){

$passed = str_replace("undefined" , " " , $passed); /*had to add this to remove the undefined value*/

$json = json_decode(stripslashes($passed));
echo"<br/>";
var_dump($json ); //this is working and dumps an array
}
```

When I call var_dump on the decoded JSON I echo an output like so...

`array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#70 (2) { ["itemCount"]=> int(0) ["ItemArray"]=>     array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#86 (6) { ["itemPosition"]=> int(0) ["planPosition"]=> int(0) ["Name"]=> string(5) "dsfsd" ["Description"]=> string(3) "sdf" ["Price"]=> string(0) "" ["Unit"]=> string(0) "" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#85 (6) { ["itemPosition"]=> int(1) ["planPosition"]=> int(0) ["Name"]=> string(4) "fdad" ["Description"]=> string(3) "sdf" ["Price"]=> string(0) "" ["Unit"]=> string(0) "" } } } }`

**The JSON**
This is the JSON I am receiving. It seems like some of the pairs don't have names? How can I access elements in this Array?

Thanks alot guys

[image: The Json I would like to parse in PHP]

Comment: "It seems like some of the pairs don't have names?" ... WHAT in the BIG BLUE MARBLE are you talking about?

Comment: Okay fair call, my JSON knowledge is limited.

Comment: off topic, but what app/tool is that json parsed in.. thats purdy :)

Comment: @Mike - it was highlighted in the webapp http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of these elements are coming back as `stdClass` objects as you can see in the `var_dump` output. You can get at the attributes with the standard object notation, for example, with your `$json` variable:

```
echo $json[0]->itemCount; // 0
echo $json[0]->itemArray[0]->itemPostion; // 0
```

You can also iterate over stdClass instances just like any PHP object, you'll be looping through the public data members, so again with your `$json`:

```
foreach(echo $json[0]->itemArray[0] as $key => $value)
  echo 'key: ' . $key . ', value: ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
```

will loop through that first object, `echo`ing out the member names and values of the object.

Comment: Thank you that's very helpful - I'm new to php - more used to Java. Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 2):

You just access them by index:

```
data[0] // first data item
```

Note that that's how you would "normally" access an array in the usual sense, so I might be missing something about your question here...